# Is it possible to unwrap based on vertex group (weight)?

Tags: uv, vertex-groups

^This
I have a dog character with all the bones properly named and have vertex groups
However, when I try to unwarp it (even with smart UV) the result is not as desirable. (It's splitting to mostly large chunks that doesn't quite make sense and also a lot of bits and pieces)
[image: Here is how it looks like with smart UV]
**I wonder if there is a way to unwrap the whole mesh to parts based on vertex group? (Each face would belong to the vertex group that has highest weight of it.**
I want the UV map to have the same number of parts as the number of vertex group. Hope it makes sense

[image: vertex groups]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot use vertex groups. To tell Blender where you want to split the mesh - how should Blender know what "makes sense", and "smart" in this case means automatically by an angle threshold which you can set while unwrapping (there you can also set the margin between the UV islands, the gaps seem quite large in your screenshot). In order to let Blender where to split the UVs you need to mark edges as seams. But even if you would select e.g. a leg group and mark the border to the body as seam, you probably need another one going down vertically to unfold the leg mesh properly.

Comment: What did not fit in the above comment: to make it a bit easier to split up the mesh in its vertex groups, you can 1. select just parts of the mesh to unwrap and so unwrap it one after another or 2. select all vertices belonging to a certain group with the _Select_ button at the bottom of _Vertex Groups_ and then in the viewport menu choose _Select_ > _Select Loops_ > _Select Boundary Loop_ to select only the border edges of the grouped vertices, then `Ctrl`+`E` > _Mark Seam_. Once you marked seams, you can also use _Select Linked_ with `L` over an area to select only that within the seams.

Comment: I'm hesitant to write this as answer because I want to give others a chance to maybe come up with a better solution where the vertex groups / weight painting might be a bigger help...

Comment: You can use geonodes to separate faces by vertex groups, join back, and now with the edges split, uv unwrap. Then you can copy the corner data to the original mesh to keep the original indices and have geometry without splits, but with UV unwraps as if there were seams on the splits. This is not clear, however: *"Each face would belong to the vertex group that has highest weight of it"*.